# DOM not getting created after getting server data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-binding

I have an issue in displaying data in front end

I am unable to recreate the table after getting data from the server (I am using DWR to get data from the server)

On clicking the header of tables i call `sort()` inside `sort()` there is a call to `getObj()` function which makes the `DWR` call to get the data,

When I click on search button I get the value of selected option and input field value and pass it to DWR call via `getObj`..... Herein lies my problem, when I am clicking on table header, the fetched data gets displayed but when I click on search button it doesn't.

Here is my controller and function-

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', []),
    selectData = [];

var inputValue='Yahoo',
    filterValue='0'
searchApp.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.filterOption=0;
    $scope.filters = [
        {id:1,value:'Campaign'},
        {id:2,value:'Account'},
        {id:3,value:'Publisher Url'},
        {id:4,value:'Email Address'}
    ];

    $scope.obj = [];
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $scope.isSorting = false;
    $scope.inputData='yahoo';

    // Default sort order
    $scope.sortValue = 'categoryId';
    $scope.isSortAsc = false;
    $scope.headList = [
        {
            name: '',
            value: '',
            css: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'Name',
            value: 'value',
            css: 'col-sort-asc'
        },
        {
            name: 'Type',
            value: 'categoryId',
            css: 'col-sort'
        }

    ]          


    // build array
    /*angular.forEach(resultsObj, function (obj, key) {
        /*$scope.filters.push({
            value: key,
            name: obj.label
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.item.length; i++) {
            $scope.results.push({
                label: obj.label,
                name: obj.item[i].name
            });
        } 


    });*/

    $scope.getObj = function() {
        // Add the dialog loader
        dialog.load.init();
        dialog.load.add('search');
        // Make the DWR call
        console.log($scope.isSortAsc,$scope.sortValue,inputValue,filterValue);
        BimDWRLogic.getSearchByCateogry($scope.isSortAsc,$scope.sortValue,inputValue,filterValue, function(obj) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.setObj(obj);
                // Complete the dialog loader
                dialog.load.complete('search');
            });
        });
    };

    // ==================================================
    // Set Object
    // ==================================================
    $scope.setObj = function(obj) {
        $scope.obj = obj;
        console.log('Length is '+$scope.obj.list.length);
        for(i=0;i<$scope.obj.list.length;i++)
        {
            console.log($scope.obj.list[i].categoryId);
            console.log($scope.obj.list[i].value);
        }
        //dialog.load.init();
        //dialog.load.add('performance-summary-chart');
        // Load the chart
        // Sometimes the div is not there
        // TODO: might be a better way of handling this
        // Don't load the chart if we are sorting
        /*if($scope.isSorting !== true){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $scope.loadChart();
            }, 500);
        }*/
        $scope.isSorting = false;
        $scope.loaded = true;

    };

    $scope.search=function(){
        inputValue=$scope.inputData;
        console.log('Input value is '+inputValue);

        $scope.getObj();


    }

    $scope.filterCriteria=function(opt){
        $scope.filterOption=opt;
        filterValue=opt;
        console.log('Selected Criteria is '+filterValue);
    }    

    $scope.sort = function(value){

        // Return if the column object is not sortable
        if(value === ''){
            return false;
        }

        // Sets the Data Value
        if(value === $scope.sortValue){
            if($scope.isSortAsc === false){
                $scope.isSortAsc = true;
            }else{
                $scope.isSortAsc = false;
            }
        }else{
            $scope.sortValue = value;
            $scope.isSortAsc = false;
        }

        // Sets the Style
        // Note: we don't loop through the first row
        for(var i=1; i<$scope.headList.length; i++){
            if(value === $scope.headList[i].value){
                if($scope.isSortAsc === true){
                    $scope.headList[i].css = 'col-sort-asc';
                }else{
                    $scope.headList[i].css = 'col-sort-desc';
                }
            }else{
                $scope.headList[i].css = 'col-sort';
            }
        }
        console.log('Inside Sort '+$scope.isSortAsc+' '+$scope.sortValue+' '+inputValue+' '+filterValue);
        // Get the object
        $scope.isSorting = true;
        $scope.getObj();

    };


});
```

Here is the html page template, i am including this page inside a jsp page

HTML Page-

```
<table class="table table-index search-results">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th colspan="3">
                        <div>Filter By:
                            <select ng-model="searchData" ng-options="f.id as f.value for f in filters" class="search-filter" ng-change="filterCriteria(searchData)">
                               <option>--none--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <th ng-repeat="th in headList" class="{{th.css}}" ng-click="sort(th.value)">{{th.name}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="resultObj in obj.list">
                    <td>{{$index + 1}}.</td>
                    <td>{{resultObj.categoryId}}</td>
                    <td>{{resultObj.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

and jsp page is 

<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="searchApp">
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
        <section class="group" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" ng-model="inputData"/><div id="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-search" ng-click="search()">Search</div>
            <div>74 results</div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <!-- Search Results -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" id="searchCtrl" ng-controller="searchCtrl"  ng-include="'views/search.htm'"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with missing controller in search result html template. 
I think it will work:

```
<table class="table table-index search-results" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
                <th colspan="3">
                    <div>Filter By:
                        <select ng-model="searchData" ng-options="f.id as f.value for f in filters" class="search-filter" ng-change="filterCriteria(searchData)">
                           <option>--none--</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th ng-repeat="th in headList" class="{{th.css}}" ng-click="sort(th.value)">{{th.name}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="resultObj in obj.list">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}.</td>
                <td>{{resultObj.categoryId}}</td>
                <td>{{resultObj.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But better way will be wrap yours sections with one tag and use one controller declaration.